# How to start with ServiceMix and activeMQ

Tags: activemq-classic, maven-3, mqtt, apache-servicemix

I wanted to start with apache ServiceMix and ActiveMQ a larger project that should grow step by step. I have experience with ActiveMQ, camel and tomcat.
Also I have read a lot about ServiceMix, but I am failing by doing the first step that is simple (I think) but not really documented somewhere:

I wanted to start my maven project so that maven will deploy my project into a standard ServiceMix installation where the first thing is only to add the following configuration the ActiveMQ of ServiceMix:

```
<transportConnectors>
   <transportConnector name="mqtt+nio" uri="mqtt+nio://localhost:1883"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

My expectation is that I could do it in the same way as I deploy tomcat projects to a Tomcat container.

How can I do thais (directory structure, maven pom) - or is it impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like to deploy your bundle to standalone ServiceMix, you can copy file of your created bundle to `$KARAF_HOME/deploy` folder. This can be done using maven.

More information about deployers can be found here: http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-3.0.x/users-guide/deployers.html

You can use **camel-maven-plugin** for debugging from IDE http://camel.apache.org/camel-maven-plugin.html

Read about **camel:run** goal  http://camel.apache.org/camel-run-maven-goal.html